# how to show static block in all pages under left column

Tags: blocks, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <block name="customer_test_left" type="core/template" template="customer/form/test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

under `app\design\frontend\default\awesome\layout\local.xml`

and

```
<?php echo "Hello World" ?>
```

under `app\design\frontend\default\awesome\template\customer\form\test.phtml`

Now the block is not showing in any page under left column

Could any one please help me...

Comment: Make sure you theme is set to `awesome` in `System->Configuration->Design`. And clear the cache.

Comment: @Marius theme is set to awesome and package is default and i have disabled cache and still clear the cache, but no use.

Comment: As Marius said: Code looks good.

Comment: Did you set default to `awesome` or only theme? If only theme, remove it use default OR set layout to awesome too!

Comment: as here i m using simple phtml echo message, so is it neccessary to specify type and do we need specify this test.phtml particular to any location

Comment: i have set template, skin, layout, default to awesome, is anything wrong here

Comment: You can try to specify an `as` attribute to the block but I don't think that's the issue. `<block name="customer_test_left" as="customer_test_left" type="core/template" template="customer/form/test.phtml" />`

Comment: @Marius: i have used "as" but no use

Comment: if anything not working like the above, how we could debug it

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Anything in logs (make sure logging is enabled)?

Comment: @Tim: No luck from logs.

Comment: then there's something you are not telling to us ;)

Comment: Where & What else i can see

Comment: some times if you are not using any html tags inside your phtml file, it may occur. so just use `<h1><?php echo $this->__('this is test') ?> </h1>` inside your phtml file and check for luck. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The page which i am looking under left column for particular block, that page xml defines remove name="left". sorry if i not provided complete information. As i m learner of magento, it took some time and provides the needed information.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the problem. I am just guessing what could be the problems:

- In Admin panel, `system` -> `Design`, Check if there are any "*Design changes*".
- In Admin panel, `system` -> `Configuration` -> `Design`:

  ```
  - In Package section, Current package name should be "default".
  - In Themes section, Default field should have the current theme name i.e "awesome".
  ```
- Try adding `semicolon` at the end of your code in template as shown below:

  ```
  <?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
  ```

Comment: for more knowledge on magento visit @ http://www.learnwebtechnologies.com/